# Flow - Missing ID for parent object when trying to create child object via Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I've got a flow set up thus far to create a Policy (custom object, master object) and want to create child records (Coverages, custom child object) but the policy ID for the newly created policy does not seem to be passing through when creating the child object record. Thoughts??

[image]

Comment: Couple of quick questions - why are you always using fast lookups - do you need multiple records to be returned each time into an sObject or collection or just a single record?. If you want to get the Policy Id for a specific record using Create record and having it assign the new record Id to a variable which you can use later on to create the child records?

Answer (score 0):

After a fast create, you can use {sObjectVariable.Id} in downstream operations (in your case, the policy id for the policy created by the fast create in step 6).

You do not need a separate fast lookup to get the policy ID.